# Changing Text Color Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im rendering text on a GLTF object using THREE.js. But i cant change the text color by passing color property to MeshPhongMaterial. Ive read the documentation and have tried everything but it just doesnt seem to work. When i use MeshBasicMaterial, it changes to white, else its black. Here's my code,

```
<script>
import * as THREE from './build/three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { GLTFLoader } from './jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import { RGBELoader } from './jsm/loaders/RGBELoader.js';
import { Vector3 } from './three.js-master/src/math/Vector3.js'
// import ObjLoader from './Loaders/OBJLoader.js'
import { RoughnessMipmapper } from './jsm/utils/RoughnessMipmapper.js';


let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
render();

function init() {

    const container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 15, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 10, 1000);
    camera.position.set( 0, 0, 0 );
    camera.position.z = 500
    const color2 = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = color2;
    new RGBELoader()
        .setDataType( THREE.UnsignedByteType )
        .setPath( './' )
        .load( 'royal_esplanade_1k.hdr', function ( texture ) {

            const envMap = pmremGenerator.fromEquirectangular( texture ).texture;
            scene.environment = envMap;

            texture.dispose();
            pmremGenerator.dispose();

            render();
            const roughnessMipmapper = new RoughnessMipmapper( renderer );

            const loader = new GLTFLoader();
            loader.load( 'obj3/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) {

                gltf.scene.traverse( function ( child ) {

                    if ( child.isMesh ) {

                        // TOFIX RoughnessMipmapper seems to be broken with WebGL 2.0
                        // roughnessMipmapper.generateMipmaps( child.material );

                    }

                } );

                scene.add( gltf.scene );
                roughnessMipmapper.dispose();
                render();

                var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
                loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {

                    var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry('Hello three.js!', {
                    font: font,
                    size: 3,
                    height: 0,
                    curveSegments: 4,
                    bevelEnabled: false,
                    bevelThickness: 0.02,
                    bevelSize: 0.05,
                    bevelSegments: 3
                    });
                    geometry.center();
                    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    color: '#ffffff',
                    specular: '#dbe4eb'
                    });
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                    mesh.position.z = 6.5;
                    mesh.position.y = 150;
                    mesh.rotateZ = 5;
                    mesh.name = "myText";
                    scene.add(mesh);
                    });

                        });

                    });

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
    renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
    renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );
    pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();

    const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
    controls.minDistance = 30;
    controls.maxDistance = 300;
    controls.target.set( 0, 135, 0 );
    controls.update();

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );
}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    render();

}

//

function render() {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a lit material like `MeshPhongMaterial`, it is required to add light sources to your scene. Or to apply an environment map to the material. Try it with this basic setup:

```js
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.4 );
scene.add( ambientLight );

const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );
dirLight.position.set( 0, 1000, 0 );
scene.add( dirLight );
```

Notice that configuring [Scene.environment](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/scenes/Scene.environment) only affects PBR materials. `MeshPhongMaterial` does not belong to this group of materials. But this explains why you glTF asset is already properly displayed.

Comment: This saved my sanity making a gameboard with beveled 3D text